# Basic triangle shader not rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I'm trying to render a triangle using openGL on iOS. I have my environment setup. I am able to change the background color of the screen. I have a basic vertex and fragment shader which both compile and link to the program successfully. glError() also reports no errors.

For some reason my triangle is not rendering.

I setup my frame buffer and render buffer like this:

```
glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
[_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:drawable];

GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,
                          GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
```

Then I define my triangle's 3 vertices:

```
_triangleMatrix[0] = -1.0; _triangleMatrix[1] = 0.0;
_triangleMatrix[2] = 0.0; _triangleMatrix[3] = 1.0;
_triangleMatrix[4] = 1.0; _triangleMatrix[5] = 0.0;
```

I create and link my shaders. I'm not going to show the whole code here since I get no compilation or link errors:

```
[self createVertexShader];
[self createFragmentShader];
[self linkProgram];
```

Then I use the program and get the attribute "position" slot and enable it:

```
glUseProgram(_program);
_position_slot = glGetAttribLocation(_program, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(_position_slot);
```

Now I need to setup my VBO. This is the part I'm most unsure of.

```
glGenBuffers(1, &_vertex_buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertex_buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(_triangleMatrix), _triangleMatrix, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

And then here's my render() method:

```
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glVertexAttribPointer(
                          _position_slot,
                          2,                  // size
                          GL_FLOAT,           // type
                          GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                          0,                  // stride
                          (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                          );
    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // Starting from vertex 0; 3 vertices total -> 1 triangle
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
```

Here's the code for the compiled vertex shader:

```
NSString* vshader = \
@"attribute vec2 position; \
void main()\
{\
    gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);\
}";
```

And the fragment shader:

```
NSString* fshader = \
@"void main()\
{\
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);\
}";
```

That's basically it, for the whole file you can check out this link:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6ed3f8231e76db35921ef260bfa6bf43

I figure the issue is that my vertex shader is not receiving the "position" data from my _triangleMatrix member. So either the attribute is not setup correctly, or the data itself from _triangleMatrix is not being read by openGL. In any case, from every tutorial and guide I've seen, I believe I have set it up correctly and I'm at a loss.

Moreover, glError() returns no error, and every shader compilation or link process that can be checked for errors report no errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: The glViewport() call was what I needed. For some reason I overlooked this and never saw it in various tutorials. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few pieces.

The most important thing you missed is to set the viewport: `glViewport(x, y, width, height)` should probably be set to the size of your render buffer. This defines what part of the buffer you are drawing to and must be set manually.

The second seems to be that you are disabling the vertex attribute array at the end of the draw call but you do not enable it at the beginning of the call. In your case the disabling is not really necessary and it only makes sense to enable it when you use the shader (`glUseProgram`). But in general make sure all the attributes that you use are enabled. In your code the triangle gets drawn only the first frame and then disappears with the next frame.